# gets elements from array?

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects:

```
var aoo = [{},{},{},....{},{},{}];
```

I need a optimized function to get element from n to m elements. Example:

```
var getEl = function(from,to){ ... return array )
```

How do it in best optimized way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var arr = aoo.slice(from, to);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your looking for the slice function. Something like

```
var getEl = myArray.slice(from, to)
```

Comment: 8 seconds in it! You get a +1 from me ;)